# DATEADD Incorrect syntax near keyword 'AS'

Tags: sql-server

Below query gives error in DATEADD parts, I can't seem to see the problem or syntax error here. Any tips on my mistake?

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - 480, fld_ConsDateTime) AS DATE) AS fld_year, 
    MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - 480, fld_ConsDateTime) AS DATE) AS fld_month, 
    fld_DeviceId, 
    SUM(fld_EnergyTotalIndexValue) AS Total_Monthly_Consumption,
    MIN(fld_ConsDateTime) AS Min_ConsDateTime, 
    MAX(fld_ConsDateTime) AS Max_ConstDateTime
FROM tbl_EM_DeviceEnergyHourlyConsumption
WHERE
    fld_Deleted = 0
    AND fld_DeviceId = 5
    AND fld_ConsDateTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -180 + 480, '2017-01-01 00:00')
    AND fld_ConsDateTime <  DATEADD(MINUTE, -180 + 480, '2017-08-01 00:00')
GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - 480, fld_ConsDateTime) AS DATE), MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - 480, fld_ConsDateTime) AS DATE), fld_DeviceId

ORDER BY fld_month ASC
```

**PS: Error message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.**

Comment: Group Bys do not use aliases. Remove those in the Group By

Comment: What's with the `AS DATE` chunks, sprinkled liberally through this sample?

Comment: I think you could remove the AS DATE bits from the query. They don't seem to have any significance.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever After Deleting AS DATE it works

Comment: your code is YEAR(whatever AS DATE), just remove AS DATE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `AS DATE` in **4 places** they shouldn't be. Here is a corrected version:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - 480, fld_ConsDateTime)) AS fld_year, 
    MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - 480, fld_ConsDateTime)) AS fld_month, 
    fld_DeviceId, 
    SUM(fld_EnergyTotalIndexValue) AS Total_Monthly_Consumption,
    MIN(fld_ConsDateTime) AS Min_ConsDateTime, 
    MAX(fld_ConsDateTime) AS Max_ConstDateTime
FROM tbl_EM_DeviceEnergyHourlyConsumption
WHERE
    fld_Deleted = 0
    AND fld_DeviceId = 5
    AND fld_ConsDateTime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -180 + 480, '2017-01-01 00:00')
    AND fld_ConsDateTime <  DATEADD(MINUTE, -180 + 480, '2017-08-01 00:00')
GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - 480, fld_ConsDateTime)), MONTH(DATEADD(MINUTE, 180 - 480, fld_ConsDateTime)), fld_DeviceId

ORDER BY fld_month ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY clause does not allow aliases. Also, don't nest your aliases in the SELECT. See below for a simplified example of what you can't do.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT)
SELECT ID,COUNT(*) FROM @Table GROUP BY ID --Works
SELECT ID AS TEST,COUNT(*) FROM @Table GROUP BY ID --Works
SELECT (ID AS TEST) AS [ThisWillBreak],COUNT(*) FROM @Table GROUP BY ID
SELECT ID,COUNT(*) FROM @Table GROUP BY ID AS [ThisWillBreak]
```